# Active Directory Get List of Users using PrincipalSearcher throws error

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, active-directory, activedirectorymembership

I have two functionality which I need to achieve in asp.net web application.

1. Authenticate using Active Directory
2. Get list of Active Directory users.

Both above work fine on client environment when I set IIS application pool to Network Service. When I change back to IIS user then only authentication works but to get the list of users stops working. I am not sure why it is happening.

Here is my code:

1. Authentication:

   ```
   public bool AuthenticateADUser(string domain, string password, string username)
   {
       bool isValid = false;

       using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain))
       {
           isValid = pc.ValidateCredentials(username, password);
       }

       return isValid;
   }
   ```
2. Get the list of Active Directory users:

   ```
   using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain))
   {
       if (groupName != string.Empty)
       {   
           // get list of users for a group
           GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, groupName);

           foreach (Principal principal in group.Members)
           {                            
               AdUsers.Add(principal);                            
           }                        
       }
       else   // get all users regardless of group
       {
           using (var searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(new UserPrincipal(context)))
           {
               foreach (Principal principal in searcher.FindAll())
               {
                   if (principal.UserPrincipalName != null)
                       AdUsers.Add(principal);
               }                            
           }  //end PrincipalSearcher using 
       }  //end else
   }  //end PrincipalContext using
   ```

Updated:
I can't say which line of code because I deployed the application to client server, so can't debug it. But here is the error:

Exception information:

```
Exception type: DirectoryServicesCOMException 
Exception message: Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.

at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean throwIfFail)
at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind()
at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_AdsObject()
at System.DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection.PopulateList()
at System.DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection..ctor(DirectoryEntry entry, String propertyName)
at System.DirectoryServices.PropertyCollection.get_Item(String propertyName)
at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.DoLDAPDirectoryInitNoContainer()
at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.DoDomainInit()
at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.Initialize()
at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.get_QueryCtx()
at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalSearcher.SetDefaultPageSizeForContext()
at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalSearcher..ctor(Principal queryFilter)
at WarshawGroup.OneVoice.User.bus_cUser.GetADUsers(String domain, String groupName)
at WarshawGroup.OneVoice.UI.Data.Users.Modify.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
at System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e)
at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

**Updated:**

It throws an exception at

```
 var searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(new UserPrincipal(context));
```

Context is PrincipalContext type...

```
 var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain);
```

PrincipalContext has property called "ConnectedServer". The value for ConnectedServer is null, so it throws the exception.

If I pass user name and password along with domain in PrincipalContext, everything works.Example...

```
 var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain,"username","pwd");
```

It seems like I need to impersonate the user who has permission to access a particular domain.

Is there any other way I can achieve this?

Thanks,

Comment: What is the exact error you're getting, and where (which line of your code) are you getting it??

Comment: I can't say which line of code because I deployed the application to client server, so can't debug it. I have updated the question with the exception. Please take a look.

Comment: If you don´t specify user and password the query will be run under the application invoker's identity, so that user should have the required privileges. That being said, NETWORK USER can query AD, while defaulting to app pool identity is a local system account which, by default, cannot.